# how to convert symfony2 datetime object from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Hi I need to check multiple dates for reminder section of my application.

But when I fetch dates from `mongodb` I am getting this:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2014-03-31 15:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

I am trying this to access date parameter but it is showing me error that `dateTime object can not converted into string`.

I am looping `dateandtime`.

Please let me know how can I access date in this situation in `symfony`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The assumption of others is that you recieve a `MongoDate` object back but you don't since I beleive Symfony actually converts it to a `DateTime`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php (I think this comes from Doctrine 2)

What you can do is use the format function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php like so:

```
$date->format('Y-M-d h:i:s')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in php (symphony is a php-framework).

All you need is something like this:

```
date('Y-M-d h:i:s', $yourDateTimeObject->sec);
```

You can also use [__toString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodate.tostring.php) method from [MongoDate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) class, but I actually prefer the previous method with `sec`.

Comment: Can you please show the code which gives you an error? And do you really do `$yourDateTimeObject->sec`? I was doing this for ages without any error.